# Check on missing imgur.com image with a simple HEAD doesn't get 404 or redirect status code

Tags: node.js, http, request, http-headers, imgur

I have two test URLs:

- deleted image: https://i.imgur.com/JedrSP3.png
- working image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luggv.png

I'm trying to do a simple request-promise request to check if this image exists before downloading it.

My test script:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

// const URL = 'https://i.redd.it/izxp34ew4nw11.jpg';
// const URL = 'https://i.imgur.com/JedrSP3.png'; // 404 imgur
const URL = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/luggv.png' // working imgur

async function main() {
  try {
    const payload = await testRp();
    debugger;
  } catch (e) {
    debugger;
  }
}

async function testRp({ increaseBy } = {}) {
  const uri = URL;
  const options = {
    method: 'HEAD',
    uri,
    json: true,
  };
  return rp(options);
}

main();
```

If you hit the deleted image link, it will redirect you to their `image has been deleted or missing` page. The problem here is that if you're getting it programmatically, you don't get a status code. You get this:

```
< { 'last-modified': 'Wed, 14 May 2014 05:44:36 GMT',
<   etag: '"d835884373f4d6c8f24742ceabe74946"',
<   'content-type': 'image/png',
<   'cache-control': 'public, max-age=31536000',
<   'content-length': '503',
<   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
<   date: 'Sat, 10 Nov 2018 22:52:05 GMT',
<   age: '4336782',
<   connection: 'close',
<   'x-served-by': 'cache-iad2145-IAD, cache-yyz8322-YYZ',
<   'x-cache': 'HIT, HIT',
<   'x-cache-hits': '63963, 8479',
<   'x-timer': 'S1541890325.130391,VS0,VE0',
<   'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, OPTIONS',
<   'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
<   server: 'cat factory 1.0' }
```

and it will seem like it's fine for you to proceed with a `GET` request.

Is there a way to check if the image exists and be guaranteed that the returned status is correct **without using the imgur API**?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything that explicitly tells you if it's a 404. But I found that the `content-length` will always be `'503'` and if you take the difference between the returned `headers` field `date` and `age`, it will always come out to be `1537553543000`.

This is obviously not failsafe as this can change at any time so you'd probably need to build a cron job to check for the these two numbers if you don't want to use the Imgur API (which has a rate limit).

Comment: the two difference numbers you showed are the same?